# Bulk insert, Cannot bulk load. Unknown version of format file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, bulkinsert, bcp

I'm having problems importing data exported using a more recent version of the `bcp` utility.

I need my exported data to be compatible with SQL server 2012.

It is my understanding that I need to add the `-V110` option when exporting data.

However, even if I add the `-V110` to the `bcp` command I always get version 12.0 (which is my bcp version) on the `FMT` file.

Here is a sample of my `bcp` call:

```
bcp [DB].[dbo].[Table1] format nul -c -f "E:\TMP\DATA\Table1.FMT" -V110 -S [SERVER] -t , -T
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: which  sql server is install .

Comment: SQL Server 2014 and I want to export files compatible with SQL Server 2012

Comment: as per my understanding if we do not put any -V option you should able to import it in any version ..

Comment: You can import any version, as long as it's a version back. So if I'm using SQL Server 2014 then I can import all versions from version 8. If it is a version above then bcp.exe displays "Cannot bulk load. Unknown version of format file"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by installing Microsoft® Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server® and adding the bcp.exe location to the path variables. Now I can export version 11 using bcp 11. You can download it from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36433

Comment: This however just provides a solution for the existing problem. I would say that there is a bug in bcp. I'll try and add a case in Microsoft.